# How can I pad an integer with zeros on the left?

Tags: java, formatting, zero-pad

How do you left pad an `int` with zeros when converting to a `String` in java?

I'm basically looking to pad out integers up to `9999` with leading zeros (e.g. 1 = `0001`).

Comment: Yup, that's it! my bad... I typed it in on my phone.  You dont' need the "new String" either : Integer.toString(num+10000).subString(1) works.

Comment: Long.valueOf("00003400").toString();  Integer.valueOf("00003400").toString(); --->3400

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35521278/printing-an-integer-in-java-that-have-zero-in-front-of-it/35521965#35521965 for a solution with diagram

Comment: There is a problem with the `new String(Integer.toString(num + 10000)).substring(1)` approach if `num` is any bigger than 9999 though, ijs.

Answer (score 1968, accepted):

Use [`java.lang.String.format(String,Object...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-) like this:

```
String.format("%05d", yournumber);
```

for zero-padding with a length of 5. For hexadecimal output replace the `d` with an `x` as in `"%05x"`.

The full formatting options are documented as part of [`java.util.Formatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html).

Comment: Should I expect the options in `String.format` to be akin to printf() in C?

Comment: If you have to do this for a large list of values, performance of DecimalFormat is at least 3 times better than String.format().  I'm in the process of doing some performance tuning myself and running the two in Visual VM shows the String.format() method accumulating CPU time at about 3-4 times the rate of DecimalFormat.format().

Comment: @Shurane mostly, yes.

Comment: And to add more than 9 zeros use something like `%012d`

Comment: This is for Java 5 and above. For 1.4 and lower DecimalFormat is an alternative as shown here http://javadevnotes.com/java-integer-to-string-with-leading-zeros

Comment: Long.valueOf("00003400").toString(); Integer.valueOf("00003400").toString(); --->3400

Comment: To get "0001" (four digits) as was asked for in the question you do "%04d". .

Comment: Hi guys! I have some problems using: `%d can't format java.lang.String arguments`

Comment: This only works to pad the String up to the number of characters specified in the format string. This **does not** add 5 zeros onto the String. More generally, this means you have to know that your string is between 0-N characters for a format string specified by "%0Nd". Any dynamic String that is longer than N, and this solution falls apart.

Answer (score 192):

Let's say you want to print `11` as `011`

**You could use a formatter**: `"%03d"`.

[image]

You can use this formatter like this:

```
int a = 11;
String with3digits = String.format("%03d", a);
System.out.println(with3digits);
```

Alternatively, some java methods directly support these formatters:

```
System.out.printf("%03d", a);
```

Comment: @Omar Koohei indeed, but it explains the reasoning behind the "magic constants".

Comment: Nice answer! Just a comment, the `F` of format() should be `f`:  `String.format(...);`.

Comment: what if i dont want to append a leading 0 but another letter/number? thanks

Comment: @chiperortiz afaik it's not possible with the above formatting tools. In that case, I calculate the required leading characters (e.g. `int prefixLength = requiredTotalLength - String.valueOf(numericValue).length`), and then use a repeat string method to create the required prefix. There are various ways to repeat strings, but there isn't a native java one, afaik: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1235179/simple-way-to-repeat-a-string-in-java

Comment: @chiperortiz starting from java 11 there is a String.repeat method though.

Answer (score 123):

If you for any reason use pre 1.5 Java then may try with Apache Commons Lang method

```
org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils.leftPad(String str, int size, '0')
```

Answer (score 36):

Found this example... Will test...

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
class TestingAndQualityAssuranceDepartment
{
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        int x=1;
        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("00");
        System.out.println(df.format(x));
    }
}
```

Tested this and:

```
String.format("%05d",number);
```

Both work, for  my purposes I think String.Format is better and more succinct.

Comment: Yes, I was going to suggest DecimalFormat because I didn't know about String.format, but then I saw uzhin's answer.  String.format must be new.

Comment: It's similar how you'd do it in .Net Except the .Net way looks nicer for small numbers.

Comment: In my case I used the first option (DecimalFormat) because my number was a Double

Answer (score 33):

Try this one:

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat; 

DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0000");

String c = df.format(9);   // Output: 0009

String a = df.format(99);  // Output: 0099

String b = df.format(999); // Output: 0999
```

Answer (score 25):

Here is how you can format your string without using `DecimalFormat`.

`String.format("%02d", 9)`

> 09

`String.format("%03d", 19)`

> 019

`String.format("%04d", 119)`

> 0119

Answer (score 23):

If performance is important in your case you could do it yourself with less overhead compared to the `String.format` function:

```
/**
 * @param in The integer value
 * @param fill The number of digits to fill
 * @return The given value left padded with the given number of digits
 */
public static String lPadZero(int in, int fill){

    boolean negative = false;
    int value, len = 0;

    if(in >= 0){
        value = in;
    } else {
        negative = true;
        value = - in;
        in = - in;
        len ++;
    }

    if(value == 0){
        len = 1;
    } else{         
        for(; value != 0; len ++){
            value /= 10;
        }
    }

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    if(negative){
        sb.append('-');
    }

    for(int i = fill; i > len; i--){
        sb.append('0');
    }

    sb.append(in);

    return sb.toString();       
}
```

**Performance**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Random rdm;
    long start; 

    // Using own function
    rdm = new Random(0);
    start = System.nanoTime();

    for(int i = 10000000; i != 0; i--){
        lPadZero(rdm.nextInt(20000) - 10000, 4);
    }
    System.out.println("Own function: " + ((System.nanoTime() - start) / 1000000) + "ms");

    // Using String.format
    rdm = new Random(0);        
    start = System.nanoTime();

    for(int i = 10000000; i != 0; i--){
        String.format("%04d", rdm.nextInt(20000) - 10000);
    }
    System.out.println("String.format: " + ((System.nanoTime() - start) / 1000000) + "ms");
}
```

**Result**

**Own function:** 1697ms

**String.format:** 38134ms

Comment: Above there's a mention of using DecimalFormat being faster. Did you have any notes on that?

Comment: @Patrick For DecimalFormat performance see also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8553672/a-faster-alternative-to-decimalformat-format

Comment: Shocking!  It's nuts that function works so poorly.  I had to zero pad and display a collection of unsigned ints that could range between 1 to 3 digits.  It needed to work lightning fast.  I used this simple method: `for( int i : data ) strData += (i > 9 ? (i > 99 ? "" : "0") : "00") + Integer.toString( i ) + "|";` That worked very rapidly (sorry I didn't time it!).

Comment: How does the performance compare after it's been run enough for HotSpot to have a crack at it?

Answer (score 18):

You can use [Google Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/):

**Maven:**

```
<dependency>
     <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
     <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
     <version>14.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

**Sample code:**

```
String paddedString1 = Strings.padStart("7", 3, '0'); //"007"
String paddedString2 = Strings.padStart("2020", 3, '0'); //"2020"
```

**Note:**

`Guava` is very useful library, it also provides lots of features which related to `Collections`, `Caches`, `Functional idioms`, `Concurrency`, `Strings`, `Primitives`, `Ranges`, `IO`, `Hashing`, `EventBus`, etc

Ref: [GuavaExplained](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/GuavaExplained)

Comment: Above sample code is usage only, not really sample code.  The comment reflect this, you would need "String myPaddedString = Strings.padStart(...)"

Comment: This method actually gives much better performance results than JDK String.format / MessageFormatter / DecimalFormatter.

Answer (score 3):

Although many of the above approaches are good, but sometimes we need to format integers as well as floats. We can use this, particularly when we need to pad particular number of zeroes on left as well as right of decimal numbers.

```
import java.text.NumberFormat;  
public class NumberFormatMain {  

public static void main(String[] args) {  
    int intNumber = 25;  
    float floatNumber = 25.546f;  
    NumberFormat format=NumberFormat.getInstance();  
    format.setMaximumIntegerDigits(6);  
    format.setMaximumFractionDigits(6);  
    format.setMinimumFractionDigits(6);  
    format.setMinimumIntegerDigits(6);  

    System.out.println("Formatted Integer : "+format.format(intNumber).replace(",",""));  
    System.out.println("Formatted Float   : "+format.format(floatNumber).replace(",",""));  
 }    
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
int x = 1;
System.out.format("%05d",x);
```

if you want to print the formatted text directly onto the screen.

Comment: But OP never asked for it. Internally `String.format` and `System.out.format` call the same `java.util.Formatter` implementation.

Comment: ... and System.out can be redirected.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a Formatter, following code uses [NumberFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html?bcsi_scan_64741547a7fe261b=0&bcsi_scan_filename=NumberFormat.html)

```
    int inputNo = 1;
    NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getInstance();
    nf.setMaximumIntegerDigits(4);
    nf.setMinimumIntegerDigits(4);
    nf.setGroupingUsed(false);

    System.out.println("Formatted Integer : " + nf.format(inputNo));
```

> Output: 0001

Answer (score 1):

**Use the class DecimalFormat, like so:**

```
NumberFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("0000"); //i use 4 Zero but you can also another number
System.out.println("OUTPUT : "+formatter.format(811));
```

**OUTPUT :** 0000811

Comment: In this case the output is 0811.

Answer (score 1):

In Kotlin, you can use format() function.

```
val minutes = 5
val strMinutes = "%02d".format(minutes)
```

where, 2 is the total number of digits you want to display(including zero).

Output: 05

Answer (score 1):

If you are on Java 15 and above,

```java
var minutes = 5
var strMinutes = "%02d".formatted(minutes)
```

where, 2 is the total number of digits you want to display(including zero).

```
Output: 05
```

This uses `formatted` method part of instance method on Strings called which does the same as the static `String.format(str,x,y,z)`

Answer (score 0):

Check my code that will work for integer and String.

Assume our first number is 2. And we want to add zeros to that so the the length of final string will be 4. For that you can use following code

```
    int number=2;
    int requiredLengthAfterPadding=4;
    String resultString=Integer.toString(number);
    int inputStringLengh=resultString.length();
    int diff=requiredLengthAfterPadding-inputStringLengh;
    if(inputStringLengh<requiredLengthAfterPadding)
    {
        resultString=new String(new char[diff]).replace("\0", "0")+number;
    }        
    System.out.println(resultString);
```

Comment: `(new char[diff])` why

Comment: `replace("\0", "0")`what is... what

Comment: @Isaac - First I created a char array, and using that char array I created a string. Then I replaced null character(which is the default value of char type) with "0" (which is the char we need here for padding)

Answer (score 0):

You can add leading 0 to your string like this. Define a string that will be the maximum length of the string that you want. In my case i need a string that will be only 9 char long.

```
String d = "602939";
d = "000000000".substring(0, (9-d.length())) + d;
System.out.println(d);
```

Output : 000602939

Answer (score 0):

Use this simple Kotlin Extension function

```
fun Int.padWithZeros(): String {
   return this.toString().padStart(4, '0')
}
```

Answer (score -3):

No packages needed:

```
String paddedString = i < 100 ? i < 10 ? "00" + i : "0" + i : "" + i;
```

This will pad the string to three characters, and it is easy to add a part more for four or five. I know this is not the perfect solution in any way (especially if you want a large padded string), but I like it.

Comment: Hmm...I like it.

Answer (score -4):

Here is another way to pad an integer with zeros on the left. You can increase the number of zeros as per your convenience. Have added a check to return the same value as is in case of negative number or a value greater than or equals to zeros configured. You can further modify as per your requirement.

```
/**
 * 
 * @author Dinesh.Lomte
 *
 */
public class AddLeadingZerosToNum {
    
    /**
     * 
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        System.out.println(getLeadingZerosToNum(0));
        System.out.println(getLeadingZerosToNum(7));
        System.out.println(getLeadingZerosToNum(13));
        System.out.println(getLeadingZerosToNum(713));
        System.out.println(getLeadingZerosToNum(7013));
        System.out.println(getLeadingZerosToNum(9999));
    }
    /**
     * 
     * @param num
     * @return
     */
    private static String getLeadingZerosToNum(int num) {
        // Initializing the string of zeros with required size
        String zeros = new String("0000");
        // Validating if num value is less then zero or if the length of number 
        // is greater then zeros configured to return the num value as is
        if (num < 0 || String.valueOf(num).length() >= zeros.length()) {
            return String.valueOf(num);
        }
        // Returning zeros in case if value is zero.
        if (num == 0) {
            return zeros;
        }
        return new StringBuilder(zeros.substring(0, zeros.length() - 
                String.valueOf(num).length())).append(
                        String.valueOf(num)).toString();
    }
}
```

**Input**

0

7

13

713

7013

9999

**Output**

0000

0007

0013

7013

9999