# Integer to two digits hex in Java

Tags: java, integer, hex

I need to change a integer value into 2-digit hex value in Java.Is there any way for this.
Thanks

My biggest number will be 63 and smallest will be 0.
I want a leading zero for small values.

Comment: You need to print it? you need to turn it into a string?

Comment: i will write into file as two-digit hex

Comment: Have you at least checked the Integer javadoc? How do you plan to convert 12345656 to a 2-digit hex value?

Answer (score 172, accepted):

```
String.format("%02X", value);
```

If you use `X` instead of `x` [as suggested by aristar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16705696/109618), then you don't need to use `.toUpperCase()`.

Comment: This is the best answer at present.

Comment: Agreed this one is much better than any of the others. It works perfectly. The only thing I would suggest is a little more description of the parameters passed to the method. I had to look up if I passed the value as an integer or as a hex string.

Comment: This unfortunately does not work for strings, you [have to use a little calculation hack](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15635584/3894977)

Comment: I know this is old, but using this method of conversion is extremely slow. If you're doing it in a loop at all, I recommend not using String.format.

Answer (score 33):

```
Integer.toHexString(42);
```

Javadoc:  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toHexString(int)

Note that this may give you more than 2 digits, however!  (An Integer is 4 bytes, so you could potentially get back 8 characters.)

Here's a bit of a hack to get your padding, as long as you are absolutely sure that you're only dealing with single-byte values (255 or less):

```
Integer.toHexString(0x100 | 42).substring(1)
```

Many more (and better) solutions at [Left padding integers (non-decimal format) with zeros in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3149692/left-padding-integers-non-decimal-format-with-zeros-in-java).

Comment: Nice zero-padding hack :)

Comment: You can use the same technique for larger values. If you want padding for up to 2-byte values you can do Integer.toHexString( 0x10000 | value).substring(1). For N hex digits you append N 0s after the "1". Of course, your hex value must have no more than N digits.

Answer (score 31):

```
String.format("%02X", (0xFF & value));
```

Comment: Can someone explain why this is doing a bit-wise and with 0xFF? This is why answers on SO shouldn't just be the code

Comment: OxFF & (byte)value just convert signed byte to unsigned. (int)-1 = 0xFFFFFFFF, (int)(-1 & 0xFf) = 0xFF

Comment: In this case, the bit-wise and with 0xFF is not necessary because of the "%02X" format.

Comment: The %02X specifier specifies a minimum of two digits. If you want exactly two digits (discarding higher bits) then you need the bitwise and.

Comment: Good to know, thanks for this additional information !

Answer (score 14):

Use [`Integer.toHexString()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toHexString%28int%29). Dont forget to pad with a leading zero if you only end up with one digit. If your integer is greater than 255 you'll get more than 2 digits.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.append(Integer.toHexString(myInt));
if (sb.length() < 2) {
    sb.insert(0, '0'); // pad with leading zero if needed
}
String hex = sb.toString();
```

Comment: Is the use of `StringBuilder` actually an improvement? http://pastebin.com/KyS06JMz

Answer (score 4):

If you just need to print them try this:

```
for(int a = 0; a < 255; a++){
    if( a % 16 == 0){
        System.out.println();
    }
    System.out.printf("%02x ", a);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

According to GabrielOshiro, If you want format integer to length 8, try this

```
String.format("0x%08X", 20) //print 0x00000014
```

Answer (score 1):

i use this to get a string representing the equivalent hex value of an integer separated by space for every byte
**EX : hex val of 260 in 4 bytes = 00 00 01 04**

```
    public static String getHexValString(Integer val, int bytePercision){
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append(Integer.toHexString(val));

    while(sb.length() < bytePercision*2){
        sb.insert(0,'0');// pad with leading zero
    }

    int l = sb.length(); // total string length before spaces
    int r = l/2; //num of rquired iterations

    for (int i=1; i < r;  i++){
        int x = l-(2*i); //space postion
        sb.insert(x, ' ');
    }
    return sb.toString().toUpperCase();         
}

public static void main(String []args){
    System.out.println("hex val of 260 in 4 bytes = " + getHexValString(260,4));
}
```