# i have managed to convert a number of bytes to hex strings but there is a ubt the 0's do not output

Tags: java, binary, hex

i have made a tool that compares file signatures, it does this by reading the first so many bytes of a file and then converting this to a hex string and then comparing this result to an array and finally prints the matching file type on a JText area, my problem is that when i go to intput a doc file - for example, the first 8 hex digits are "50 4B 03 04" but when it prints this out on the JText area i get 504B34, now i think its because zero in binary is 0000....and with a 4 (50 4B 03 '04')i think it is 00000100 so i think the code is just not outputting the first 4 bytes if it is a zero, does anybody know how to include all the zero's?

ok guys, i know my problem and i can post it to explain, as you can see this is a snippet of my code in where i make a string builder to turn bytes into hex, the problem is that i have tried to format the string builder with with sb.append("%02x.. etc but i dont think it is doing anything what so ever to the string builder when i have put it in the headerData line:

```
}
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                    for(byte b:a){
                     sb.append(String.format("%02x", b));
                    }
                        if (i != -1) {
        HeaderData unknownHead = new HeaderData(" ", (sb.toString()));
```

Comment: what's `ubt` in question title??

Comment: Yes, I know how to do that, but without you showing some code I cannot tell you where & what you need to change.

Comment: ubt = problem and i have coding but theres too much to post on here, i know mobody like a lot of coding

Comment: This is my coding but this does output the zero's but i have intergated it into my coding just the same and then printed the result in a JTextArea on the command of a button click:

Comment: @fvu i have put the coding that is causing the problem in the description

Comment: @user2135994 that fragment of code by itself works fine - except maybe for the missing blank in the format string.  I also tried `textArea.append(sb.toString());` which adds it to an empty JTextArea,works fine as well.  What's that `HeaderData` object?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Integer to two digits hex in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8689526/integer-to-two-digits-hex-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

```
String.format(" %02x", bytes[i] & 0xFF)
```

---

```
    byte[] a = {(byte)3, (byte)-128, (byte)-4, (byte)3, (byte)0,
                (byte)1, (byte)127};
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (byte b : a) {
        sb.append(String.format("%02x ", b));
    }
    System.out.println(sb.toString());
```

Result:

```
03 80 fc 03 00 01 7f
```

Comment: i have this in my coding already and the zero's still do not show

Comment: With 02? Furthermore I added a space to separate the numbers for clarity.

Comment: i have put the snippet of my coding at the top of the page, i think the string builder is not being formatted by the %02x line, somehow skipping it

Comment: I have added test code. I think the error lies somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

Well `Integer.toHexString(byte b)`  should do

**Code**

```
byte[] a = {(byte)10, (byte)-120, (byte)-14,  (byte)0,
        (byte)1, (byte)127};

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (byte b : a) {
    sb.append(Integer.toHexString(b)+" ");
}

System.out.println(sb.toString());
```

**Result**

```
a ffffff88 fffffff2 0 1 7f
```