# Can we use String.format() to pad/prefix with a character with desired length?

Tags: java, string, format

Can `java.lang.String.format(String str, String str1)` be used for adding prefix of a particular character.

I could do this for a number like:

```
int sendID = 202022;
String usiSuffix = String.format("%032d", sendID);
```

It makes a `String` of length 32 and leftpadded with 0s : `00000000000000000000000000202022`

How to achieve the same thing when sendID is a `String` like:

```
String sendID = "AABB";
```

And I want an output like: `0000000000000000000000000000AABB`

Comment: Many solutions here - [How to format a java string with leading zero?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4051887/how-to-format-a-java-string-with-leading-zero)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/391978/2123124 looks like what you need i believe

Comment: @adarshr I have already looked into that answer, that does not answer my question.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use this hackish way to get your output:

```
String sendID = "AABB";
String output = String.format("%0"+(32-sendID.length())+"d%s", 0, sendID);
```

#### Demo: http://ideone.com/UNVjqS

Comment: For anybody wanting to pad a string with trailing zeroes, you can use a very similar approach. String.format("%s"+"%0"+(32-sendID.length())+"d", sendID, 0);

Answer (score 13):

You can do as below if you really want to use `String.format`,

```
String sendID = "AABB";
String.format("%32s", sendID ).replace(' ', '0')
```

Other than `String.format` you can find many solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4051887/how-to-format-a-java-string-with-leading-zero).

**Edit**: Thanks for Brian to point of the issue. The above wont work for input with spaces. You can try as below. But I wont suggest the below operation as it has too many string operation.

```
String sendID = "AA BB";
String suffix = String.format("%32s", "").replace(' ', '0') + sendID;
sendID = suffix.substring(sendID.length());
```

You can also try using [StringUtils.leftPad](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#leftPad%28java.lang.String,%20int,%20char%29)

```
StringUtils.leftPad(sendID, 32 - sendID.length(), '0');
```

Comment: What happens if he wants to pad "AA BB" ?

Comment: @BrianAgnew the code may be changed like the following:
    `String sendID = "AA BB";`
    `String usiSuffix =  String.format("%32s", "").replace(' ','0');`
    `sendID = usiSuffix+sendID;`

Comment: @learningloop: That will be just too many String operations to get a simple task done :)

Answer (score 5):

You can't use `String.format()` for padding with arbitrary characters. Perhaps Apache Commons [StringUtils.leftPad()](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#leftPad(java.lang.String,%20int)) would be of use for a concise solution ? Note there's also a `StringUtils.rightPad()` too.

Answer (score 2):

I just add some Java 8 code if someone need it in future:

```
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(leftpad("m m", 2, '@'));
        System.out.println(leftpad("m m", 5, '@'));
    }

    static String leftpad(String s, int nb, char pad) {
        return Optional.of(nb - s.length())
                .filter(i -> i > 0)
                .map(i-> String.format("%" + i + "s", "").replace(" ", pad + "") + s)
                .orElse(s);
    }

}
```

This version supports adding any char as padding

Comment: Is there a reason you do `replace(" ", pad+"")` (i.e. using the substring signature of `replace`) rather than simply `replace(' ', pad)`?

Comment: No. Just write in IDE and `replace(" ", pad+"")` was „faster” in type.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved this issue using the base jdks String.format function

```
String sendId="AABB";
int length=20;
String.format("%"+length+"s",sendId).replaceAll(" ","0")
```

Comment: Be aware that this will change any spaces within sendID to zeroes, which may cause problems depending on your domain.