# String.format - Fill a String with dots

Tags: java, string, string-formatting

I have two Strings.

```
String a = "Abraham"
String b = "Best Friend"
```

I want an output similar to this:

```
Abraham.......OK
Best Friend...OK
```

I used String.format() to get the following result.

```
a = String.format("%0$-" + b.lenght() + "s   ", a);
b = String.format("%0$-" + b.lenght() + "s   ", b);

Abraham       OK
Best Friend   OK
```

I can not use String.replace(), because the space between "Best" and "Friend" would be replaced as well.

I found a solution for putting zeroes in front of the beginning of the String. However, i dont understand in which way I should modify this solution to get the desired output.

[answer by anubhava](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15635273/can-we-use-string-format-to-pad-prefix-with-a-character-with-desired-length)

```
String sendID = "AABB";
String output = String.format("%0"+(32-sendID.length())+"d%s", 0, sendID);
```

I found solutions with padded Strings, but i would like to solve this with the String.format()-Method.

Comment: might be something here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388461/how-can-i-pad-a-string-in-java

Comment: I'd not use `String.format()` here but use a `StringBuilder` and add the dots in a loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd probably use a loop for that (along with a `StringBuilder` for performance reasons:

```
public String pad(String source, int targetLength, String pad) {
  StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder( source );
  for( int i = source.length(); i < targetLength; i+=pad.length() ) {
    result.append(pad);
  }
  return result.toString();
}

//calling:
a = pad( a, 32, "." );
```

Note that this would stop early if `targetLength - source.length()` is not a multiple of `pad.length()`. To fix that either only pass single characters or handle the last part by using `pad.substring(...)` with appropriate values.

*Edit:*

Here's a version with `pad.subString(...)`:

```
public String pad(String source, int targetLength, String pad) {
  StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder( source );    
  while( result.length() < targetLength ) {
    result.append(pad.substring( 0, Math.min( pad.length(), targetLength -  result.length() ) ));
  }
  return result.toString();
}
```

Comment: The solution with StringBuilder seems to be very fitting for my usecase.

Comment: In my usecase, pad should allways be a single character, therefore i decided to make it a character and then "cast"(concatenate) it to a String.

Comment: @replayleif there's no need for the "cast", `StringBuilder` has a `append(char)` method.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `replaceAll()` with a regex like this:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

class Ideone
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        String arr[] = {"Abraham", "Best Friend"};
        for(String s:arr)
            System.out.println(String.format("%-"+32+"s", s).replaceAll("\\s(?=\\s+$|$)", ".")+"OK");
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Abraham.........................OK
Best Friend.....................OK
```

http://ideone.com/Rb886w

Answer (score 1):

A simple **recursive method** to do it would be:

```
public static String fill(String s, int l){
    if(s.length()==l)
        return s; // Return the String , as the task is complete
    else 
        return fill(s+".",l); // Append 1 .(dot) and again call the method
}
```

This is the **simplest** way I can think of.

So, for you, it would be:

```
a = fill(a,b.length());
b = fill(b,b.length());
```

Comment: Just as a sidenode: if `l` is large and the initial string is short this can lead to serious memory problems since each recursion will create at least one intermediate string. Thus I'd suggest using a `StringBuilder` internally, i.e. for the actual recursive calls.

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought..

```
public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String TEN_DOTS = "..........";
    String TEST_STR = "foo";
    String outstr = TEST_STR + TEN_DOTS;
    System.out.println(outstr.substring(0,10));
  }
}
```

Outputs:

```
foo.......
```

Answer (score 0):

Since Java 11 we can use [String.repeat(int count)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#repeat(int)) to duplicate a String **count** times.

```java
public static String padLeft(String source, int targetLength, Character pad) {
  return String.valueOf(pad).repeat(Math.max(0, targetLength - source.length())) + source;
}

public static String padRight(String source, int targetLength, Character pad) {
  return source + String.valueOf(pad).repeat(Math.max(0, targetLength - source.length()));
}
```