# Convert int to hex string

Tags: java

I have an int number as 1238, when I convert to hex string with Integer.toHexString function, it will return me 4d6. Is there any possible way that I can format so it will return me 04d6 ? It would be great if you can provide solution for general case, not this specific case.
Thank you.

Comment: Whats wrong with triggering "0" + Integer.toHexString() ? And just to be precise: I would suggest to use "0x" as prefix - "0" is typically the prefix for OCTAL numbers; not hex.

Comment: This is an excellent problem to use as a learning experience.  Work it out on your own.  (There are about 20 different ways to handle it, so it should not be too hard to find one.)

Comment: This post shows how to do this for 2 digits: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8689526/integer-to-two-digits-hex-in-java That's easy to extend to 4 digits

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> It would be great if you can provide solution for general case, not
>   this specific case

This is a quick solution that will add a left 0 in the case the hex string length is not a multiple of 2.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.append(Integer.toHexString(myInt));
if (sb.length() % 2 > 0) {
    sb.insert(0, '0'); // pad with leading zero if needed
}
String hex = sb.toString();
```

Answer (score 3):

```
System.out.println(String.format("%04x",1238));  ->  "04d6"
System.out.println(String.format("%#04x",1238)); -> "0x4d6"
```

Comment: Doesn't work on larger inputs like 123899

Comment: The question was only about integers

Comment: What I mean is, your solution is clever, but only for a small integer like 1238, not, say, 123899

Comment: It just solves the problem described in the problem. Your solution solves a problem never mentioned in the question. You don't know if the original problem is really "string length is not a multiple of 2" as the question does not mention it.

Comment: Te be fair, he first gives a specific example, but then states "It would be great if you can provide solution for general case, not this specific case". I was trying to address his latter requirement.