# How can I pad a hexadecimal digit with 0 in java?

Tags: java, string, hex, number-formatting

I'm trying to pad a hexadecimal digit with 0's in the beginning so that the length of it is always 4. For example, the FF is going to be padded as 00FF. I have tried to use String.format("%04d", number) but it didn't work as my hexadecimal digit is actually a string.
I have also tried using StringUtils.leftPad() but for some reason, IntelliJ couldn't detect it.

Please note my count is going to change, but I haven't represented it here as I'm yet to implement it. This is my sample code. Thanks.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int count = 0;
        String orderID = Integer.toHexString(count).toUpperCase();
        System.out.println(String.format("%04d", Integer.valueOf(orderID)));
        
    }
```

Comment: `String orderID = Integer.toHexString(count).toUpperCase(); String.format("%04d", Integer.valueOf(orderID))` ... What? Just get rid of the first line and pass in `count` to `String.format`. There is no reason to go from `int` to `String` back to `int` just to format another `String`.

Comment: Use `format` directly to format the integer to hex (use `X` instead of `d` in the format string).

Comment: Possibly related: [Integer to two digits hex in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8689526) -> `System.out.printf("%04X", count);`. You can add `%n` at the end of format to generate line separator similarly to what `println` does: `System.out.printf("%04X%n", count);`

Comment: @tkausl, that was a method that I tried, of course, it isn't correct, and in the end, I need a string, not an int.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
String.format("%04x", 255)
```

with output

```
00ff
```

(or use `X` for uppercases hex digits)

As @user16320675 point, more info about `Formatter` [here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Formatter.html).

Comment: it worked. I couldn't find about `X` before, thank you for your answer!