# Generating sequence number in java

Tags: java

I want to generate a sequence number starting from 00000001,00000002....(i need all these zero as well)Please help me..Thanks in advance..

Comment: None of the answer are from XSLT, and you've accepted one. Retagging

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can just generate the sequence numbers as integers and then format them like this:

```
String.format("%08d", yournumber);
```

See this question:
[How can I pad an integers with zeros on the left?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/473282/left-padding-integers-with-zeros-in-java)

Answer (score 2):

You just need to use [string formatting](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax) to pad numbers with zeros:

```
for (int i = 1; i < 1000; i++) {
    String sequence = String.format("%08d", i);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just maintain that variable as an integer and use `String.format` to format it.

```
String s = String.format ("%08d", 42); // gives you "00000042"
```