# Fill strings with 0's using formatter

Tags: java, formatter

I know I can fill with spaces using :

```
String.format("%6s", "abc"); // ___abc ( three spaces before abc
```

But I can't seem to find how to produce:

```
000abc
```

Edit:

I tried `%06s` prior to asking this. Just letting you know before more ( untried ) answers show up.

Currently I have: `String.format("%6s", data ).replace(' ', '0' )`  But I think there must exists a better way.

Comment: BTW, I used `%06s` prior to asking this, just letting you know before more ( untried ) answers show up.

Answer (score 7):

You should really consider using [StringUtils](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#leftPad%28java.lang.String,%20int,%20char%29) from  Apache Commons Lang for such String manipulation tasks as your code will get much more readable. Your example would be `StringUtils.leftPad("abc", 6, ' ');`

Answer (score 1):

Try rolling your own static-utility method

```
public static String leftPadStringWithChar(String s, int fixedLength, char c){

    if(fixedLength < s.length()){
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(s);

    for(int i = 0; i < fixedLength - s.length(); i++){
        sb.insert(0, c);
    }

    return sb.toString();
}
```

And then use it, as such

```
System.out.println(leftPadStringWithChar("abc", 6, '0'));
```

**OUTPUT**

```
000abc
```

Answer (score 1):

By all means, find a library you like for this kind of stuff and learn what's in your shiny new toolbox so you reinvent fewer wheels (that sometimes have flats).  I prefer [Guava](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Strings.html#padStart%28java.lang.String,%20int,%20char%29) to Apache Commons.  In this case they are equivalent:

```
Strings.padStart("abc",6,'0');
```

Answer (score 0):

Quick and dirty (set the length of the "000....00" string as the maximum len you support) :

```
public static String lefTpadWithZeros(String x,int minlen) {
   return x.length()<minlen ? 
       "000000000000000".substring(0,minlen-x.length()) + x : x;     
}
```

Answer (score -1):

[I think this is what you're looking for.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/473282/left-padding-integers-with-zeros-in-java)

```
String.format("%06s", "abc");
```

Comment: The how about this?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388461/padding-strings-in-java/388482#388482