# A faster alternative to DecimalFormat.format()?

Tags: java, performance, profiling, string-formatting

In order to improve its performance, I have been profiling one of my applications with the VisualVM sampler, using the  minimum sampling period of 20ms. According to the profiler, the main thread spends almost a quarter of its CPU time in the [`DecimalFormat.format()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html#format%28double%29) method.

I am using `DecimalFormat.format()` with the `0.000000` pattern to "convert" `double` numbers to a string representation with exactly six decimal digits. I know that this method is relatively expensive and it *is* called a lot of times, but I was still somewhat surprised by these results.

1. To what degree are the results of such a sampling profiler accurate? How would I go about verifying them - preferrably without resorting to an instrumenting profiler?
2. Is there a faster alternative to `DecimalFormat` for my use case? Would it make sense to roll out my own `NumberFormat` subclass?

**UPDATE:**

I created a micro-benchmark to compare the performance of the following three methods:

- `DecimalFormat.format()`: Single `DecimalFormat` object reused multiple times.
- `String.format()`: Multiple independent calls. Internally this method boils down to

  ```
  public static String format(String format, Object ... args) {
      return new Formatter().format(format, args).toString();
  }
  ```

  Therefore I expected its performance to be very similar to `Formatter.format()`.
- `Formatter.format()`: Single `Formatter` object reused multiple times.

  This method is slightly awkward - `Formatter` objects created with the default constructor append all strings created by the `format()` method to an internal `StringBuilder` object, which is not properly accessible and therefore cannot be cleared. As a consequence, multiple calls to `format()` will create a *concatenation* of all resulting strings.

  To work around this issue, I provided my own `StringBuilder` instance that I cleared before use with a `setLength(0)` call.

The results where interesting:

- `DecimalFormat.format()` was the baseline at 1.4us per call.
- `String.format()` was slower by a factor of two at 2.7us per call.
- `Formatter.format()` was also slower by a factor of two at 2.5us per call.

Right now it looks that `DecimalFormat.format()` is still the fastest among these alternatives.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can write your own routine given you know exactly what you want.

```
public static void appendTo6(StringBuilder builder, double d) {
    if (d < 0) {
        builder.append('-');
        d = -d;
    }
    if (d * 1e6 + 0.5 > Long.MAX_VALUE) {
        // TODO write a fall back.
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("number too large");
    }
    long scaled = (long) (d * 1e6 + 0.5);
    long factor = 1000000;
    int scale = 7;
    long scaled2 = scaled / 10;
    while (factor <= scaled2) {
        factor *= 10;
        scale++;
    }
    while (scale > 0) {
        if (scale == 6)
            builder.append('.');
        long c = scaled / factor % 10;
        factor /= 10;
        builder.append((char) ('0' + c));
        scale--;
    }
}

@Test
public void testCases() {
    for (String s : "-0.000001,0.000009,-0.000010,0.100000,1.100000,10.100000".split(",")) {
        double d = Double.parseDouble(s);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        appendTo6(sb, d);
        assertEquals(s, sb.toString());
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    long start = System.nanoTime();
    final int runs = 20000000;
    for (int i = 0; i < runs; i++) {
        appendTo6(sb, i * 1e-6);
        sb.setLength(0);
    }
    long time = System.nanoTime() - start;
    System.out.printf("Took %,d ns per append double%n", time / runs);
}
```

prints

```
Took 128 ns per append double
```

If you want even more performance you can write to a direct ByteBuffer (assuming you want to write the data somewhere) so the data you produce does need to be copied or encoded. (Assuming that is ok)

NOTE: this is limited to positive/negative values of less than 9 trillion (Long.MAX_VALUE/1e6) You can add special handling if this might be an issue.

Comment: +1 I was about to write something myself - this piece of code could be a nice starting point.

Comment: I finally wrote a formatter using my own algorithm and it's about four times faster than `DecimalFormat` for the functionality subset that I need. I believe that there is still room for improvement, since I did not actually go down to the level of appending individual digits. I'll accept this answer since it is the only one that contains usable code.

Comment: Great job Peter. I have reused your code to create fast `double` and even twiece faster `String` (containing double value) formatter.

Comment: @dantuch using this approach you can reduce or even eliminate any garbage produced.

Comment: Using yours that uses StringBuilder as argument, to not produce any Strings dring this method invocation? And sorry - I wan't precise writing that using String in place of double (that my method would have to convert to String) is `twiece faster`. It's ~4,5x faster ~231 ns. double to String = ~963ns. String.format that creates exactly the same output = ~7632ns.  And you code takes on my machine ~540ns. All per 1 method invocation. 2,000,000 runs.

Comment: So working on provided StringBuilder is almoust 2x faster than creating StringBuilder in it, and converting it to String at the end. I could try to work with char array in place of StringBuilder, that could give some improvement.

Comment: I use a similar form write to a direct ByteBuffer which is re-usable and writeable directly to an NIO channel. I do the reverse to read data from such a buffer which means it can read/write text to/from double without creating any objects such as Strings. https://github.com/peter-lawrey/Java-Chronicle/blob/master/src/main/java/vanilla/java/chronicle/impl/AbstractExcerpt.java

Comment: Thanks for sharing! Anyway do you know any reliable way of comparing 2 algorithms speed? I was comparing, as mentioned above, using `StringBuilder` object vs `char[]` for translating `double` to `String` and results vary (ssometimes it's 600ns, and later it goes to 1400ns...), even if I do 10x runs of both x 10k-1M times.

Comment: I would look at your GCs and ensure this is not impacting you with `-verbosegc` If you have eliminated this, I would look at using thread affinity to lock the cpu to your thread as this can reduce jitter.

Comment: The supported range mentioned here is incorrect - e.g. `Long.MAX_VALUE / 1e6 - 1` will cause it to enter an infinite loop. But this is a great starting point.

Comment: @amichair it would break, without reporting an error, but not go into an inifinite loop. It would be work checking the input range to make sure it can print the value.

Comment: @PeterLawrey I tried it, and it enters an infinite loop - did I miss something? I think it happens because of the comparison `factor * 10 <= scaled` - for large enough values the multiplication by 10 overflows, so the comparison always evaluates to true.

Comment: @amichair You are right, I have added a size check.

Comment: @PeterLawrey Still hangs. This is a tricky one :-) The problem is that there are long values larger than the largest multiple of 10 representable by a long, and the `factor * 10` check breaks for them. One possible fix is `factor * 10 <= scaled && factor * 10 > 0`. Or the more efficient(?) `factor * 10 <= scaled && factor < 1000000000000000000L`. Or `factor * 10d <= scaled` with double arithmetic. Or one can limit the range to less than the largest long multiple of 10, but that's a bit of a waste. Also, the new size check is missing the negative side of the range.

Comment: @amichair I see what you mean. How about the change above?

Comment: @PeterLawrey I think that's ok, and a nice optimization. Worth adding a comment explaining the shenanigan imho. And fixing the range check for negatives. Thanks for the updates!

Comment: One last thing worth noting for anyone wanting to use this for higher precision requirements - this algorithm is not a drop-in replacement for DecimalFormat. It doesn't treat -0.0, infinity and NaN as DecimalFormat does, which you can add if necessary. More importantly, it could lose some precision and print out slightly different values in edge cases (due to loss of resolution when using doubles). It's probably ok for most use cases - if precision is that important, you should probably be using BigDecimal or custom fixed-point values rather than doubles anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe your program doesn't do much intensive work and so this appears to do the most - crunching some numbers.

My point is that your results are still relative to your app.

Put a timer around each DecimalFormatter.format() and see how many millis you are using to get a clearer picture.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative would be to use the string [Formatter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html), give it a try to see if it performs better:

```
String.format("%.6f", 1.23456789)
```

Or even better, create a single formatter and reuse it - as long as there are no multithreading issues, since formatters are not necessarily safe for multithreaded access:

```
Formatter formatter = new Formatter();
// presumably, the formatter would be called multiple times
System.out.println(formatter.format("%.6f", 1.23456789));
formatter.close();
```

Comment: re-using would be good but formatters are not thread safe so you'd have to check whether this particular formatter can handle multiple threads (as for instance in a web application)

Comment: @extraneon thanks for the comment, I edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: Both `String.format()` and `Formatter.format()` appear to be slower than `DecimalFormat.format()`. I suspect it's because the pattern string has to be parsed each and every time. `Formatter.format()` is also harder to reuse - see my edit for details.

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer (write your own custom formatter) is correct but OP's desired format is somewhat unusual so probably won't be that helpful to others?

Here is a custom implementation for numbers that: require comma separators; have up to two decimal places. This is useful for enterprisey-things like currencies and percentages.

```
/**
 * Formats a decimal to either zero (if an integer) or two (even if 0.5) decimal places. Useful
 * for currency. Also adds commas.
 * <p>
 * Note: Java's <code>DecimalFormat</code> is neither Thread-safe nor particularly fast. This is our attempt to improve it. Basically we pre-render a bunch of numbers including their
 * commas, then concatenate them.
 */

private final static String[] PRE_FORMATTED_INTEGERS = new String[500_000];

static {
    for ( int loop = 0, length = PRE_FORMATTED_INTEGERS.length; loop < length; loop++ ) {

        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder( Integer.toString( loop ) );

        for ( int loop2 = builder.length() - 3; loop2 > 0; loop2 -= 3 ) {
            builder.insert( loop2, ',' );
        }

        PRE_FORMATTED_INTEGERS[loop] = builder.toString();
    }
}

public static String formatShortDecimal( Number decimal, boolean removeTrailingZeroes ) {

    if ( decimal == null ) {
        return "0";
    }

    // Use PRE_FORMATTED_INTEGERS directly for short integers (fast case)

    boolean isNegative = false;

    int intValue = decimal.intValue();
    double remainingDouble;

    if ( intValue < 0 ) {
        intValue = -intValue;
        remainingDouble = -decimal.doubleValue() - intValue;
        isNegative = true;
    } else {
        remainingDouble = decimal.doubleValue() - intValue;
    }

    if ( remainingDouble > 0.99 ) {
        intValue++;
        remainingDouble = 0;
    }

    if ( intValue < PRE_FORMATTED_INTEGERS.length && remainingDouble < 0.01 && !isNegative ) {
        return PRE_FORMATTED_INTEGERS[intValue];
    }

    // Concatenate our pre-formatted numbers for longer integers

    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

    while ( true ) {
        if ( intValue < PRE_FORMATTED_INTEGERS.length ) {
            String chunk = PRE_FORMATTED_INTEGERS[intValue];
            builder.insert( 0, chunk );
            break;
        }
        int nextChunk = intValue / 1_000;
        String chunk = PRE_FORMATTED_INTEGERS[intValue - ( nextChunk * 1_000 ) + 1_000];
        builder.insert( 0, chunk, 1, chunk.length() );
        intValue = nextChunk;
    }

    // Add two decimal places (if any)

    if ( remainingDouble >= 0.01 ) {
        builder.append( '.' );
        intValue = (int) Math.round( ( remainingDouble + 1 ) * 100 );
        builder.append( PRE_FORMATTED_INTEGERS[intValue], 1, PRE_FORMATTED_INTEGERS[intValue].length() );

        if ( removeTrailingZeroes && builder.charAt( builder.length() - 1 ) == '0' ) {
            builder.deleteCharAt( builder.length() - 1 );
        }
    }

    if ( isNegative ) {
        builder.insert( 0, '-' );
    }

    return builder.toString();
}
```

This micro-benchmark shows it to be 2x faster than `DecimalFormat` (but of course YMMV depending on your use case). Improvements welcome!

```
/**
 * Micro-benchmark for our custom <code>DecimalFormat</code>. When profiling, we spend a
 * surprising amount of time in <code>DecimalFormat</code>, as noted here
 * https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-7050528. It is also not Thread-safe.
 * <p>
 * As recommended here
 * http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8553672/a-faster-alternative-to-decimalformat-format
 * we can write a custom format given we know exactly what output we want.
 * <p>
 * Our code benchmarks around 2x as fast as <code>DecimalFormat</code>. See micro-benchmark
 * below.
 */

public static void main( String[] args ) {

    Random random = new Random();
    DecimalFormat format = new DecimalFormat( "###,###,##0.##" );

    for ( int warmup = 0; warmup < 100_000_000; warmup++ ) {
        MathUtils.formatShortDecimal( random.nextFloat() * 100_000_000 );
        format.format( random.nextFloat() * 100_000_000 );
    }

    // DecimalFormat

    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

    for ( int test = 0; test < 100_000_000; test++ ) {
        format.format( random.nextFloat() * 100_000_000 );
    }

    long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println( "DecimalFormat: " + ( end - start ) + "ms" );

    // Custom

    start = System.currentTimeMillis();

    for ( int test = 0; test < 100_000_000; test++ ) {
        MathUtils.formatShortDecimal( random.nextFloat() * 100_000_000 );
    }

    end = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println( "formatShortDecimal: " + ( end - start ) + "ms" );
}
```