# Binary format of an integer

Tags: java

I have a method that prints out binary formar of numbers:

```
private static void binary(int n){
   for(int i = 1; i < Math.pow(2, n); i++)
      System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(i));
   }
}
```

Output is like for n = 3:

```
1
10
11
100
101
110
111
```

Is there a way to print out like this:

```
001
010
011
100
101
110
111
```

Comment: Unfortunately String.format/Formatter doesn't have a binary format. :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    private static void binary(int n){
       String t = ""; int N = 1<<n;
       for (int i=0; i<n;i++) t += "0";
       for (int i = 1; i < N; i++) {
             String s = Integer.toBinaryString(i);
             System.out.println(t.substring(s.length())+s);
       }
    }
```

Comment: if n = 4, I have to change "000" to "0000"!

Comment: @Sam Fixed, sorry. I hadn't got the exact requirement.

Comment: A good interview question: What is the most inefficient part of this code and how could you change it? ;)

Comment: is it `String s` inside the loop? just declare it outside the loop.

Comment: Moving the declaration doesn't change the performances. Peter might have been pointing to the repeated use of Math.pow (it's a slow function but maybe it's automatically optimized by compilers today for powers of 2). Using StringBuilders instead of concatenating strings might have an impact but probably barely measurable. What's really slow here is the println but you can't really avoid it, you just could do it less often.

Answer (score 2):

I would write it as

```
private static void binary(int n){
   for(long i = 0, max = 1 << n; i < max; i++) {
      String s = Long.toBinaryString(i);
      while (s.length() < n) s = '0' + s;
      System.out.println(s);
   }
}
```

or more efficiently

```
private static void binary(int n) {
    char[] chars = new char[n];
    for (long i = 0, max = 1 << n; i < max; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
            chars[j] = (char) (((i >>> (n - j - 1)) & 1) + '0');
        System.out.println(chars);
    }
}

binary(3);
```

prints

```
000
001
010
011
100
101
110
111
```

Answer (score 2):

Quick/Dirty version:

```
System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(i+(1<<n)).substring(1));
```

(obvious flaw if n == the number of bits in an integer, or if you have more bits in your integer than you want to print... so limited, but maybe a bit simpler if you know your inputs)

Comment: A slightly different scheme is to concat "0000" to the front of the string and then take a fixed-length tail.  The only problem is that Java doesn't have a `tail()` method, so you have to do ugly computation to figure the starting point.

Comment: Yes, but the other solutions here already did that, so I decided to show a (mostly) numerical alternative.

Comment: (But I've used your solution in the past, too.)

Comment: The other solutions sure went around Robin Hood's barn to do it.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
String.format("%" + n + "s", Integer.toBinaryString(i)).replace(' ', '0')
```

It may not be the most efficient solution, but it's simple and short enough.

Answer (score 0):

```
private static void binary(int n){
   for(int i = 1; i < Math.pow(2, n); i++)
      System.out.println(String.format("%04d", Integer.parseInt(Integer.toBinaryString(i))));
   }
}
```

[How can I pad an integers with zeros on the left?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/473282/left-padding-integers-with-zeros-in-java)

Comment: That's wrong. the return value of `Integer.toBinaryString` is `String`, not integer.

Comment: Edited, I realised that as I posted. Come to think of it I don't really like how it has to be parsed again.