# add leading zeros dynamically relative to input number

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Left padding integers with zeros in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/473282/left-padding-integers-with-zeros-in-java)

I need to add some leading zeros dynamically relative to input number length, for example if I input 10 the it will output

Numbers
01
02
03
04
05
06
07
08
09
10

I think the way to do it is to get the length of the numbers input and then apply that value to the counter using some formatting, just not sure the best way of going about that.

This is what I have so far.. (I am very new to programming)

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    int numbers;
    int counter = 1;
    int padlength;

    Scanner ngrabber = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter numbers to output number");
    numbers = ngrabber.nextInt();


                System.out.println("Numbers");
                while (counter <= numbers)          
                {
                    padlength = String.valueOf(numbers).length();
                    System.out.println(counter);
                    counter++;
                }


        }       
    }
```

Comment: You should try a printf style function

Comment: Google : "java zero padding" give you instant answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `printf` which uses [Formatter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html) for padding here:

```
System.out.printf("%02d ", counter);
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use Java's printf style functions as shown [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html)

```
System.out.printf("%02d ",counter);
```

Unless I am not clear of the syntax, The `2` will make sure that the length of the printed number is a min of 2, and the `0` means pad with `0` if the length of the input number is less than 2.

---

Edit: To change number dynamically, try this.

```
padlength = String.valueOf(numbers).length();
System.out.printf(String.format("\%0%dd " ,padlength),counter);
```

Comment: yes that works in part but the "%02d" needs to be dynamically relative to input number length

Comment: @user1985625 thats what padding means, try it out..

Comment: If you mean u need to support 3 digit numbers etc dynamically, you can generate the string that you pass there..

Comment: Yes that is what I am trying to do, just not sure on the syntax

Comment: @user1985625 try my edit, not sure if it is flawless, but you should be able to grasp the idea

Answer (score 0):

`printf` is the right answer for Java. 
If you ever find yourself needing to do this in a brain-dead environment
(e.g., a Windows command script, a.k.a. batch file), here’s an approach:

> Convert your upper bound number to a string; e.g., 10 –> "10"
>   Get the length of that string: `strlen("10") = 2`
>   Append that many zero characters (`0`) to a one character (`1`): `strcat("1","0","0") = "100"`
>   Convert that string to a number: "100" –> 100
>   For each number that you want to format: add the above number (1 + 100 = 101), convert to a string (101 –> "101"), and strip off the first character ("101" –> "01").

Yes, this is a kludge.  Anybody know a better way to do it on Windows?