# Leading zeroes trim issue in CSVWriter in java

Tags: java, csv

I am using [CSVWriter](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/apidocs/au/com/bytecode/opencsv/CSVWriter.html) to create a csv file in java. The problem is that the leading zeroes are getting trimmed in the generated csv.

For example:
if I am giving *0001*
then its writing *1* and all leading zeroes are ***trimmed***.

A solution to this problem was to append a **=** before the no. So *="0001"* is giving me the right answer. But the problem is how to append **=** using csvwriter. CSVWriter automatically appends **"** **"** to the input so giving *=0001* as input it generates **"=0001"** but I want **="0001"**. 
A solution to this was to use CSVWriter.NO_QUOTE_CHARACTER in the CSVWriter constructor and it doesn't append **""**. But now it is generating **=0001** and I want **="0001"**.
Any idea how can I keep quotes (**""**) and append an **=** before the number??

Comment: Some reference code would be useful.

Comment: This might answer your problem.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/473282/left-padding-integers-with-zeros-in-java?rq=1

Comment: @JigarPatel I am able to lpad zeroes in java. I am already sending 0001 as input. But it gets trimmed after CSV is generated.

Comment: Are you passing a number (0001) to CSVWriter? Can you post some code snippet here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrade to version 1.8 or later.