# Add 0 to Month: i.e. "1" -> "01"

Tags: android, format

I'm doing the conversion of the month, the format (LONG) to an integer. But the months are converted without the 0. I must add the 0 of the months lower 10. How can I do?

```
    String month = monthSelector.getSelectedItem().toString();
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    try {
        cal.setTime(new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM").parse(month));
    } catch (ParseException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    int monthInt = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1;
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/473282/left-padding-integers-with-zeros-in-java

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what I do:

```
int monthInt = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1; 
String monthConverted = ""+monthInt;
if(monthInt<10){
monthConverted = "0"+monthConverted;
}
```