# How to add Leading Zero with getMonth in Java (Android)

Tags: java, android, date, getdate

I'm using an int variable:

```
month = dp.getMonth() + 1;
```

currently getting an output of "2" and when I do the following:

```
if (month<10){
                month = '0'+month;
            };
```

I get:  50.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Your problem is that your `'0'` `char` is being coerced to an integer. Since `'0'` has an ASCII  value of `48`, you're getting `48 + 2 = 50`.

Note that what you're trying to do won't work - you can't add a leading `0` to `month`, as `month` is a number. A leading zero only makes sense in a *string representation* of a number.

As explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/473309/622391), here's how to produce a zero-padded number:

```
String.format("%02d", month);
```