# Generate Random Numbers By Adding 0 Infront SELENIUM

Tags: java

How do I generate a random integer i, such that i belongs 01 , 02 , 03 , 04 and the range gap within 01 to 10. if integer = 10 remove 0 infront.

I tried to use this:

```
Random generator = new Random();
int i = generator.nextInt(10) + 1;
but it gives me values between [0,10).
```

But in my case I need them to be `(01 , 02 , 03 , 04 , 05)` etc.

Comment: You should cast your number to String and append 0 if number has one digit.

Comment: @wawek do you mind show me example of the code? thanks

Comment: Please separate the *number* from the *formatting*. 1) what *distribution* of numbers to you want to generate, and 2) how do you want them *formatted*?

Comment: i want the number that been generate as 01, 02 , 03 , 04 by append 0 infront of it

Comment: Please only add tags that are relevant to the question. I removed the `selenium` and `automation` tags.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I pad an integers with zeros on the left?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/473282/how-can-i-pad-an-integers-with-zeros-on-the-left)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
Random generator = new Random();
int i = generator.nextInt(10) + 1;
System.out.println(String.format("%02d", i));
```

- `0` for pad with `zero`
- `2` for width to `2`

Answer (score 0):

The is the code snippet:

```
int i = r.nextInt(10)+1;
String s = String.valueOf(i);
if (s.length() == 1) {
    s= "0" + s;
} 
System.out.println(s);
```

Answer (score 0):

The int variable will never display the first `0`'s so you'll have to use a `String` object :

```
int i = generator.nextInt(10) + 1;
String s = i == 10 ? "" + i : "0" + i;
```