# Adding number with zero in left pad

Tags: java, loops, padding, increment

First of all Sorry for foolish question As i am new to java. actually i have a string which contains a number in between i want to increment its value up to some specific number. i am very confused how to explain . below is the example what i need to do.

I have a string i.e :- 

*"03000001da**00000001**666666"*

and i want to increase its value like below

*"03000001da**00000002**666666"*

*"03000001da**00000003**666666"*

*"03000001da**00000004**666666"*
etc.

I wrote a simple java code below:

but its print wrongly i.e:- 
*"03000001da**2**666666"*

*"03000001da**3**666666"*

*"03000001da**4**666666"*
etc.

```
public class Demo {

public static void main(String[] args) {
        String content = "03000001da00000001666666";

        String firstIndex = content.substring(0, 10);
        String requireIndex = content.substring(10,18);
        String lastIndex  = content.substring(18, content.length());
       for(int i = 0; i <= 10;i++){
           System.out.println(firstIndex + (Integer.parseInt(requireIndex)+i) + lastIndex);
       }
    } 
}
```

need some help please help me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I pad an integers with zeros on the left?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/473282/how-can-i-pad-an-integers-with-zeros-on-the-left)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String content = "03000001da00000001666666";

    String firstIndex = content.substring(0, 10);
    String requireIndex = content.substring(10,18);
    String lastIndex  = content.substring(18);
    for(int i = 0; i <= 10;i++){
        System.out.printf("%s%08d%s%n",firstIndex, Integer.parseInt(requireIndex)+i, lastIndex);
    }
}
```

Comment: `Integer#parseInt` should be moved outside the loop

Comment: It is not meant to be optimal here it is only to show the idea based on his code

Answer (score 1):

You can use `printf` and a format `String` (like `%08d`) to pad your `int` at 8 characters with leading zeros. You can also parse your `int` once before you loop and [`String.substring(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring-int-) (with only one parameter) reads the rest of the `String` by default. That might look something like,

```
String content = "03000001da00000001666666";
String firstIndex = content.substring(0, 10);
String lastIndex = content.substring(18);
int middle = Integer.parseInt(content.substring(10, 18));
for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
    System.out.printf("%s%08d%s%n", firstIndex, middle + i, lastIndex);
}
```

Comment: I think internally `Arrays.fill()` also use a loop. I am not able to figure out the issue with my answer below. Would you help me point it out?