# How to increment a number with zeros of +1, preserving the 0?

Tags: php, increment

In php, when I increment:

```
$numb = "00001";
$numb = $numb +1;
```

The result is **2**.

How do I keep the zeroes and having `00002` ?

Useful link for [BASH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21592667/how-can-i-increment-a-number-in-a-while-loop-while-preserving-leading-zeroes-ba) and for [JAVA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36409136/adding-number-with-zero-in-left-pad) but not able to think of a php version.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
$numb = "00001";
$numb = $numb +1;
echo str_pad($numb, 5, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

https://3v4l.org/gah5c

Comment: Wonderful! I found str_pad somewhere in the documentation and an example but couldn't understand how to work with it! i'll be able to mark this question in some minutes. Thank you!

Comment: In this case only `$numb = 1` would be enough. :)

Comment: @SougataBose I don't know why people always want to have numbers with zeros in front of... Nobody told them that its bad practice to have data like that? If its just for displaying okay... but often they're saving the numbers exactly this way to a DB.. I'll never understand.

Comment: what if number of zeros is dynamic?

Comment: @Twinfriends Well.. If you access the database from other ways too. Say a BI software, then having the leading zeros is probably vital. But either way, what the OP asks for, the OP gets. (unless it's way out there)