# How to set the number of digits while printing in Java?

Tags: printing, numbers, integer, number-formatting

I couldn't really clarify what I'm asking in the title. I an integer for a day and a month. I have to print the month with a 0 in front of it if it's one digit only.

For example 04 if month = 4 and so on.

This is how it's supposed to look like in C#:

```
Console.WriteLine("{0}.{1:00}", day, month);
```

Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I pad an integers with zeros on the left?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/473282/how-can-i-pad-an-integers-with-zeros-on-the-left)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int month = 4;
DecimalFormat formater = new DecimalFormat("00");
String month_formated = formater.format(month);
```

Comment: Thank you!


Note: Gotta import java.text.DecimalFormat;

Answer (score 0):

Besides [the answer Fernando Lahoz](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40695782/7170434) provided (which is pretty specific to your case: decimal formating) you can also use [`System.out.format`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#format-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-) in Java which allows you to specify a format-string while printing to System.out (the `format` function is applicable to any `PrintStream` though). In your case

```
System.out.format("%2d %2d", day, month)
```

should do the trick. The `%d`is used for decimal integers and you can then specify any width you want just before the 'd' (2 in your case).

If you want to access the string formed for later use and not (only) print it you can use [`String.format`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-). It uses the same format as `System.out.format` but returns the String that is formed.

A complete syntax for all formats(string, decimal, floating point, calendar, date/time, ...) can be found [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax).
If you'd like a quick tuto on number-formatting you can check [this link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberformat.html) or [this link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/formatting.html) instead.

Good luck!

Comment: Wow, uhm.. Thanks. I really didn't expect an answer that full and committed. <3

Comment: Haha my pleasure  ;)