# Android Time Picker getting correct value from TimePicker

Tags: android, timepicker

I am trying to get the hour and minute value from a TimePicker View. When I use the code below I get the correct value, but if the minute value has a zero, for example the time 3:04, the below code will produce 3:4 instead of 3:04.

```
String time = viewTime.getCurrentHour()+":"+ viewTime.getCurrentMinute();
```

Comment: Just format minutes with leading zero

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I pad an integers with zeros on the left?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/473282/how-can-i-pad-an-integers-with-zeros-on-the-left)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option here is to use `String.format()` with an appropriate mask to get two digit number strings for the hour and minute.

```
int hour = viewTime.getHour();
int minute = viewTime.getMinute;
String time = String.format("%02d:%02d", hour, minute);
```

Note that I have replaced your call to `TimePicker#getCurrentHour()` with `TimePicker#getHour()`, as the former has been deprecated since API level 23.  Check the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TimePicker.html) for more information.

Comment: I am going to try this code now would let you know if it works

Comment: Yea reason why I used the deprecated version cause i was using a older API