# Concatenation of integers in string

Tags: java

I have a string as follows

```
String str = "AUTHOR01BOOK"
```

In this string I want to add this number `00001`. How can I do that?

I tried concatenate it but the output I got is `AUTHOR01BOOK1`. My code is not appending zeros. How can I do that?

Comment: What is your expected output?  And can you share your code with us?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I pad an integers with zeros on the left?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/473282/how-can-i-pad-an-integers-with-zeros-on-the-left)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the print format.

```
String str="AUTHOR01BOOK";
int num = 000001;

System.out.printf("%s%06d", str, num);
```

or use the String.format function to store it in a variable:

```
String myConcat = String.format("%s%05d", str, num);
```

EDIT:
To answer raju's follow up question about doing this in a loop,
Create a method that will return the formatted string:

```
static String myConcatWithLoop(String str, int iteration){

    return String.format("%s%05d", str, iteration);
}
```

then call this in your loop:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
        System.out.println(myConcatWithLoop(str, i));

}
```

Comment: Can you expand your answer to get the String as well? Instead of just displaying it.

Comment: %s is for string and %d is for decimal.. the 06 is for padding and also you can search for printf. There are many documentations and samples.

Comment: @TraxX he means he wants to save the result in a variable. In answer just prints it.

Comment: You can use the String.format and store it in a variable

Comment: Hi Trax,  suppose I put this inside a for loop and I want to change 00001 to 00002 till 100 but my requirement is 00001 should always be 5 digit means when loop comes to 10 number should be 00010 and when it is 100 it should be 00100. How can I do this by following your answers.  It would be helpful if you can explain me this by code

Comment: Hi Traxx can you please explain me your solution in detail? I am facing some problem in understanding this

Comment: Should I explain about the first problem about printing or the loop one?

Comment: %s is for string and %06d is for decimal. '0' in '%06d' your zero padding while '6' is the number of additional padding which "num variable" is included. So when we use '%06d' and num is 1 then the value is 000001 which is 5 zeros and 1.

Answer (score 0):

if you store '000001' in int datatype it will treat as an octal. That is

int a=000001; 
**System.out.println(a);
Output: 1** 
It will treat it as OCTAL number

So you cannot store a number beginning with 0 in int as compiler will typecast it. Therefore for that you have to work with Strings only :)

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below code. It not only displays but also changes the string.
    StringUtils help us to pad the left zeros.
    Number 4 in the leftPad method denotes the number of zeros.
    Its not a dynamic solution but it fulfills your need.

```
import org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils;
public class Interge {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int i =00001;
        String s= i+"";
        String result = StringUtils.leftPad(s, 4, "0");
        String fnlReslt = "AUTHOR01BOOK"+result;
        System.out.println("The String : " + fnlReslt);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is use `StringBuilder`

```
public class JavaApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JavaApplication ex = new JavaApplication();
        String str = "AUTHOR01BOOK";
        System.out.println(ex.paddingZero(str));
    }

    public String paddingZero(String str) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append(str);
        sb.append("00001");
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```