# Java verify that date is in current week

Tags: java, date

I have a date which is in the form of a string "05/30/2018" and i want to determine that it is in this current week.I convert it to date format using this method:

```
    public Date convertStringToDate(String dateString) {
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    Date dateInString = null;

    try {

        Date date = formatter.parse(dateString);
        dateInString = date;
        System.out.println(date);
        System.out.println(formatter.format(date));

    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return dateInString;
}
```

And to check if its within the same week i use this method :

```
    public boolean isDateInCurrentWeek(Date date) {

    Calendar currentCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    int week = currentCalendar.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR);
    int year = currentCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    Calendar targetCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    targetCalendar.setTime(date);
    int targetWeek = targetCalendar.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR);
    int targetYear = targetCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);

    boolean belongs = (week == targetWeek && year == targetYear);

    return belongs;
}
```

And i use both methods like this:

```
 if(CustomDateClass.isDateInCurrentWeek(convertStringToDate(trans.getTransactionDate()))){
// perform some task
}
```

The verification always fails and produces a false on every date even today's date. I have looked at other methods suggested in other questions and the results are the same. What could i have missed that is causing the method not to produce the correct result.

Comment: I notice that you said your input is in this format: 05/30/2018 but you're using `SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");`

Comment: Mandatory "you should be using `java. time` instead of `java.util.date`".

Comment: For me, this is just a typo in the pattern used.

Comment: Per  daniu… FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Comment: Erent, your question is clear and shows some research effort. What could likely have helped yourself would be [to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I consider the chances good that in this process you wold have been able to solve the problem yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is that the date format `05/30/2018` does not matches `dd/MM/yyyy`.

Use instead `MM/dd/yyyy`.

Comment: Thank you, i ddnt see that at all

Comment: While the fix works, I still think that the diagnosis isn’t precise. At least part of the trouble is that when `SimpleDateFormat` with standard settings gets a month of 30, to which it ought to object, it just gives you a nonsense result back and pretends all is well. If it would only throw an exception with an explanatory message, the programmer would easily discover the mistake and would not need to ask here on Stack Overflow. There is a fix to force the expected exception, but rather than worrying about it I would recommend you don’t use that troublesome class at all.

Answer (score 4):

## tl;dr

```
org.threeten.extra.YearWeek.from(                     // Represent a standard ISO 8601 week, starting on a Monday, where week # 1 contains first Thursday of the calendar year.
    java.time.LocalDate.parse(                        // Parse an input string into a `LocalDate` object, representing a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone.
        "05/30/2018" ,
        DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "MM/dd/uuuu" )   // Define a formatting pattern to match the input string. The Question’s code failed to do so correctly.
    )
)                                                     // Returns a `YearWeek` object.
.equals(
    YearWeek.now(                                     // Get the current standard ISO 8601 week.
        ZoneId.of( "Atlantic/Canary" )                // Get the week for today’s date as seen in the wall-clock time in use by the people of a certain region (a time zone). 
    )                                                 // Returns a `YearWeek` object.
)
```

## Details

The [Answer by Arvind](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50616522/642706) is correct in that your formatting patterns fails to match your input string. But you have other problems too.

## java.time

You are using terrible old date-time classes that were supplanted years ago by the modern *java.time* classes.

### `LocalDate` parsing

Parse your input string as a `LocalDate`. By the way, whenever possible, use standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format when exchanging date-time values as text.

```
String input = "05/30/2018" ;
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "MM/dd/uuuu" ) ;
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse( input , f ) ;
```

> ld.toString(): 2018-05-30

### Define week

You must define what you mean by "week". Your use of the troublesome `Calendar` class results in a week defined by the cultural norms of the JVM’ current `Locale`.

I suspect you may wish to be more specific in your definition of a week, so that your results do not vary at runtime.

For example, we could use the standard [ISO 8601 definition of week](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date). The standard week starts on a Monday, and week # 1 has the first Thursday of the calendar year. The year holds either 52 or 53 weeks. The last/first few days of the calendar year may land in the next/previous week-based year.

We can access the week-based year and week number of a `LocalDate` by using the [`IsoFields`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/temporal/IsoFields.html) enum.

```
int weekOfWeekBasedYear = ld.get ( IsoFields.WEEK_OF_WEEK_BASED_YEAR );
int weekBasedYear = ld.get ( IsoFields.WEEK_BASED_YEAR );
```

Let's make a string of those values in standard ISO 8601 format. The standard requires we pad any single-digit week number with [a leading zero](https://stackoverflow.com/q/473282/642706).

```
String weekIso = 
    weekBasedYear + 
    "-W" + 
    String.format("%02d", weekOfWeekBasedYear) 
;
```

> 2018-W22

### Current week

You want to compare your input date’s week to the current week. To get the current week, we need the current date.

A time zone is crucial in determining a date. For any given moment, the date varies around the globe by zone. For example, a few minutes after midnight in [Paris France](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Europe/Paris) is a new day while still “yesterday” in [Montréal Québec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal).

If no time zone is specified, the JVM implicitly applies its current default time zone. That default may change at any moment, so your results may vary. Better to specify your desired/expected time zone explicitly as an argument.

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `continent/region`, such as [`America/Montreal`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal), [`Africa/Casablanca`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Africa/Casablanca), or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 3-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ;  
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( z ) ;
```

If you want to use the JVM’s current default time zone, ask for it and pass as an argument. If omitted, the JVM’s current default is applied implicitly. Better to be explicit, as the default may be changed at any moment *during runtime* by any code in any thread of any app within the JVM.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.systemDefault() ;  // Get JVM’s current default time zone.

int todayWeekOfWeekBasedYear = ld.get ( IsoFields.WEEK_OF_WEEK_BASED_YEAR );
int todayWeekBasedYear = ld.get ( IsoFields.WEEK_BASED_YEAR );
```

Make a String as we did above.

```
String todayWeekIso = todayWeekBasedYear + "-W" + String.format("%02d", todayWeekOfWeekBasedYear) ;
```

Compare.

```
boolean isDateInCurrentWeek = weekIso.equalsIgnoreCase​( todayWeekIso ) ;
```

### Shortcut: `DateTimeFormatter.ISO_WEEK_DATE`

Rather than extracting the week & year numbers to build a String, we can let a `DateTimeFormatter` do that same work. The constant [`DateTimeFormatter.ISO_WEEK_DATE`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ISO_WEEK_DATE) generates a String in standard ISO 8601 week format, including the day-of-week number (1-7 for Monday-Sunday).

```
String inputWeekDate = ld.format( DateTimeFormatter.ISO_WEEK_DATE ) ;
```

> 2018-W22-3

Do the same for the current week.

```
String currentWeekDate = today.format( DateTimeFormatter.ISO_WEEK_DATE ) ;
```

> 2018-W22-3

Truncate the last two characters, the hyphen and day-of-week number.

```
String inputWeek = inputWeekDate.substring( 0 , 8 ) ;
String currentWeek = currentWeekDate.substring( 0 , 8 ) ;
```

Compare.

```
boolean isDateInCurrentWeek = inputWeek.equalsIgnoreCase​( currentWeek ) ;
```

## *ThreeTen-Extra* library

This work of handling weeks is easier if we add the [*ThreeTen-Extra*](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) library to our project. Then we can make use of its [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html) class.

```
YearWeek yearWeekThen = YearWeek.from( ld ) ;
YearWeek yearWeekNow = YearWeek.now( ZoneId.of( "Europe/Berlin" ) ) ;

boolean isDateInCurrentWeek = yearWeekThen.equals( yearWeekNow ) ;
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Comment: very extensive and helpful explanation, Thank you