# Java - why skipping zeros when reading from a file

Tags: java, file

Why does my program ignore zeros when reading from a file?
For example, here are the numbers from the file:

```
0001 0011 0010
```

Then this is my output:

```
1
11
10
```

This is my code:

```
    File file = new File("num.txt");
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
    while (scanner.hasNext()) {
        if (scanner.hasNextInt()) {
            System.out.println(scanner.nextInt());
        } else {
            scanner.next();
        }
    }
```

Comment: That's because you are using hasNextInt(). Use like this instead: System.out.println(scanner.next());

Comment: All numbers do that.  You either need to format the number so it *\*prints\** with leading zeros, or you need to read it as a string.

Comment: Also see here, if you really need it to be an integer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/473282/how-can-i-pad-an-integer-with-zeros-on-the-left

Comment: The values are being read as an `int` which doesn't store leading zeros.  Search on formatting, or possibly read as a String.

Comment: what kind of output you are expecting from the program?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `scanner.next()` instead of `scanner.nextInt()`.

Using `scanner.nextInt()` will remove any leading zeros, since 0001 == 1.