# Convert a Long/ULong to an unsigned hexadecimal string with padding zeros

Tags: java, kotlin, formatting, number-formatting, long-integer

How to convert a `Long`/`ULong` representing an unsigned long to an unsigned hexadecimal string with padding zeros (a 16-digit hexadecimal string)?

I am looking for a simple and neat solution in Kotlin or Java.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
val mutableList = listOf(121212L, 121212121212L,-1L)
mutableList.forEach {
    println(it.toULong().toString(16).padStart(16, '0'))
}
```

it gives

```
000000000001d97c
0000001c38ce307c
ffffffffffffffff
```

Edited: Credit to Ilya in the comment for the missing toULong part.

Comment: This doesn't work for numbers represented by minus longs (greater than or equal to 2^63). For example, for a number stored as -1 I want "ffffffffffffffff", but this solution gives "00000000000000-1".

Comment: The only missing part here is converting a long value to ULong before invoking toString: `it.toULong().toString(16).padStart(16, '0')`

Comment: Although this solution is longer and looks more complicated than the one I found below using `String.format`, it only runs for about 10% of the time it takes to run mine. It's probably because parsing a format string is slow. So this is indeed a better answer.

Answer (score 2):

I have found the solution using `x`/`X` in `String.format()`:

```
fun Long.to16DigitUnsignedLowercaseHexString() =
    "%016x".format(this)

fun Long.to16DigitUnsignedUppercaseHexString() =
    "%016X".format(this)
```

I have tested that it works for boundary values `0L`, `1L`, `Long.MAX_VALUE`, `-1L`, and `Long.MIN_VALUE`, so there should be no problems.

A similar question is asked in [java - How can I pad an integer with zeros on the left? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/473282/how-can-i-pad-an-integer-with-zeros-on-the-left). When looking at this for the first time, I didn't expect it to work because I thought that `x`/`X` is for signed hexadecimal formatting. It turned out I was wrong and `x`/`X` is exactly for unsigned hexadecimal formatting.