# How to keep leading zero when storing integer value with leading zero in Arraylist without using String?

Tags: java, arraylist

I wish to store some phone number in arraylist and if the number contain leading zero ,i want to store in arraylist as it is, without removing leading zero. how can i achieve that .

```
ArrayList<Integer> Restrict = new ArrayList<Integer>();
cars.add(01);
cars.add(02);
cars.add(3);
cars.add(4);
System.out.println(cars.get(0));
```

> output

```
1
```

how can i get `01` instead of 1.

Comment: Store a string.

Comment: Integers don't store any leading zeros, as only the actual integer value is stored. But when printing, you could pad the resulting string like shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/473282/how-can-i-pad-an-integer-with-zeros-on-the-left

Comment: @maloomeister How would you know not to pad 3 and 4? You can't

Comment: Are car 1 and 01 two different cars?

Comment: @Michael of course, you are right. They would have to know which numbers to pad himself. I just showed him a way to pad his integers, how they use that knowledge is not my worry.

Comment: Only possible by storing them as `String` or format them in your output using `String.format("%02d", myNum)`

Comment: i wish to know if i can store as integer  with leading zero .. storing as string is not an option .for me

Comment: @bdc No, you can't.

Answer (score 3):

You can store them as strings

```
ArrayList<String> Restrict = new ArrayList<>();
        cars.add("01");
        cars.add("02");
        cars.add("3");
        cars.add("4");

    System.out.println(cars.get(0));
```

Answer (score 1):

### `Integer` is the wrong type for this requirement

A phone number consists of a minimum of `10` digits (first digit from 1-9) and it can go well beyond the maximum limit of `Integer` which is `2147483647`.

Apart from this, the `0` at the beginning of an `Integer` means it's radix is `8` i.e. it represents an octal number e.g.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int x = 0123;
        System.out.println(x);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
83
```

Note that (0123)<sub>8</sub> = (83)<sub>10</sub>

The right type for this requirement is `String` i.e. you should declare your `List` as follows:

```
List<String> restrict = new ArrayList<>();
```

and store the numbers as

```
restrict.add("01234567890")
restrict.add("1234567890")
```

Also, always follow the [Java naming conventions](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/codeconventions-namingconventions.html) e.g. the name of the variable can be `restrict` but should not be named as `Restrict` (as in your code).

Comment: While this is a good answer, I can't help but feel your effort is misplaced

Comment: @Michael - Thanks for the feedback. No worries, I posted it anyway because I was half-way while this was closed. If it can be helpful for anyone, that's the best reward I will have for this effort.